# url_for is using HTTP instead of HTTPS in FastAPI

Tags: python, https, jinja2, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a html file and I configured the URL of the links as below.

```
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

{{ url_for('static', path='css/style.css') }}
```

I have got the domain creation for the application with nginx and haproxy.

When the html page is loaded the css and js stylings are not being loaded as it is using http instead of https.

[Flask url_for generates http instead of https when running by docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287411/flask-url-for-generates-http-instead-of-https-when-running-by-docker)

[FastAPI links created by url_for in Jinja2 template use HTTP instead of HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70521784/fastapi-links-created-by-url-for-in-jinja2-template-use-http-instead-of-https)

I went with some of the links on similar issue but didn't help as it is for html files.

When I hardcoded it worked. How can I make this static. I am using the uvicorn fastapi.

Comment: Depending on which of your proxies are terminating https, that reverse proxy needs to set `X-Forwarded-Proto` - otherwise the application behind it can't know that it's being served through https.

Comment: In your NGINX configuration, try redirecting port 80 to 443. I Googled my way to what appears to be a good configuration example in the following Digital Ocean community post answer: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-redirect-to-https

Comment: After adding `HTTPSRedirectMiddleware`  I can't relaod the html page as well. It says  ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: @chris In answer comments I saw Use `HTTPSRedirectMiddleware`. This will enforce redirection to https on any incoming requests. My application link is already requesting the index page html in https only. when loading the html the styling links are being called as http. That is the issue. How to make it https ?

Comment: Removing url_for and replacing with href="/static/css/style.css" worked for me.

Comment: Replacing the `url_for` function with relative URLs (e.g., `href="/static/<YOUR_FILE>"`), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71306247/17865804), is the easiest solution in your case. The `HTTPSRedirectMiddleware` enforces **all** incoming requests to be redirected to `HTTPS` (including requests to your static files). As for the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error, there might likely be some issue with redirection when you are behind a proxy, see [this](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/199#issuecomment-1210368890). Have a look [here](https://serverfault.com/q/933355) as well.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at Uvicorn's documentation on [Running behind Nginx](https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-behind-nginx).

Answer (score 6):

In my case, FastAPI and uvicorn was behind reverse proxy on fly.io and have to add `--proxy-headers` and `--forwarded-allow-ips '*'` to my uvicorn command. Full example:

```
uvicorn app:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --proxy-headers --forwarded-allow-ips '66.241.124.179'
```

To find IP address:

```
➜ fly ips list      
VERSION IP                  TYPE            REGION  CREATED AT           
v6      2a09:8280:1::1:de8b public          global  2023-02-11T11:24:14Z    
v4      66.241.124.179      public (shared)
```

How it's works?

1. Uvicorn starts hanlding incomming request.
2. If `--proxy-headers` is enabled, uvicorn pass proxy headers further:
   `X-Forwarded-Proto`, `X-Forwarded-For`, ...
3. Then uvicorn for incoming request trying to detect schema in [ProxyHeadersMiddleware](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py#L64) middleware
4. In that middleware uvicorn parses client IP address from `X-Forwarded-For` header.
5. Then compares that IP address to trusted list (`--forwarded-allow-ips`)
6. If address is trusted, then extracts schema from `X-Forwarded-Proto`

Answer (score -2):

One way to ensure that `url_for` always generates https URLs is to set the `PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME` configuration option to `https` in your application. This will instruct `url_for` to use the `https` scheme unless explicitly overridden. Here is an example:

```
app = FastAPI()
app.config["PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME"] = "https"
```

Comment: This seems like a Flask config not FastAPI. Perhaps you can delete it not to spend people's time unnecessarily.